# How to handle exceptions thrown by the method in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

How to handle exceptions thrown by the method ? It is necessary that the method didn't throw the exception in the method 'check'

```
 <?php 
class AllAccidents 
{
  public static function check() {
    try {
        $x = 1;
        if($x) 
        throw new Exception("Value must be more than 1");

    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo "hello>>".$e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}

class Test 
{
   public function go(){
     try{
        AllAccidents::check();
     } catch (Exception $e){

     }
   }
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->go();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've formatted your code like this and you can set your logic when you want to throw exception

```
<?php 
class AllAccidents 
{
  public static function check() {
    try {
        self::checkNum(2);

    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

 public static function checkNum($number) {
    if($number>1) {
      throw new Exception("Value must be 1 or below");
    }
  return true;
 }
}

class Test 
{
   public function go(){
     try{
        AllAccidents::check();
     } catch (Exception $e){

     }
   }
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->go();
?>
```